# Package sierotki.el doesn't work under Emacs-snapshot

Tags: emacs, latex, elisp, emacs23, emacs24

For a couple of years I used to use the [`sierotki.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/sierotki.el) package ([NonbreakableSpace](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NonbreakableSpace)) in Emacs for my LaTeX writing. It worked very well in my configuration (Ubuntu 12.04, emacs 23 or emacs 24 (24.2.1)). Some time ago I've installed the emacs-snapshot (emacs 24.3.50.1) (from ppa:cassou/emacs ppa) and `sierotki.el` doesn't work anymore (without any errors).

Anybody knows what is wrong?

---

For the sake of completeness, the package just inserts `~` (nonbreakable space in LaTeX) after one-letter words (like `I`, `a` in English, or many others in my native language).

Comment: "doesn't work anymore" is insufficiently informative. Please supply a specific test case, explaining what you do, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: Might as well be not related to the Emacs version at all. Do you use AUCTeX?  If so, did you update it recently?  Also, why don't you use `tildify-buffer` which is built-in to Emacs and apparently does the very same thing.

Comment: @lunaryorn: sierotki.el is to tildify as flyspell to spell-check-buffer (roughly).

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `sierotki.el` used to use the variable `last-command-char`, which was changed to `last-command-event` in more recent Emacsen.  You might want either to upgrade `sierotki.el` (I contacted the author some time ago with this fix, and he applied it), or fix it yourself.